# Error de tipo no detectado: no se puede leer la propiedad 'length' de null (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

```js
function addRowDT(data) {
    var tabla = $("#tbl_pacientes").DataTable();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        tabla.fnAddData([
            data[i].IdPaciente,
            data[i].Nombres,
            (data[i].ApPaterno + " " + data[i].ApMaterno),
            ((data[i].Sexo == 'M')? "Masculino": "Femenino"),
            data[i].Edad,
            data[i].Direccion,
            ((data[i].Estado == true)? "Activo": "Inactivo")
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Debes colocar todo el codigo :v

Comment: el error es bastante descriptivo. La variable "data" está llegando con valor null

Comment: haz un console log de data para saber como viene, el error, como dice @xero399 es que te está llegando data como un null, es decir que no se lo estás mandando bien desde donde llamas a la función

Answer (score 1):

El error te está indicando que la variable que estás utilizando en el bucle, tiene el valor null, con lo cual no puedes leer su propiedad length.

Deberías controlar esta posible situación y sólo hacer el for en el caso que no venga a nulo

```
if (data!= null) {
--- código
}
```

Espero que te sirva